# zsh: tab rotates between directories, what key to select and enter one?

Tags: bash, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

I am trying to complete path within a directory tree. When I press tab at any directory level, completion rotates among all possible directory completions. Is there a way to bind a key to "select" & enter a directory to then hit tab again and complete the files/directories in that folder?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>/</kbd> will select the currently-displayed directory and allow you to continue completing inside it (using <kbd>Tab</kbd> again).